# Check pixel color and trigger a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, applescript, compare, pixel

How can we check the color of a determined pixel(x,y) and, if it is equal to a certain value, run a bash script.

In particular I'd like to write a script that:

1. Wait for a determined key being pressed (in particular 'j' or 'f' or 'space' or 'y').
2. Compare the color of 4 pixels to a color. If we found that one or
   more (if there are more we can pick the first or a random one) we
   can go to step 2.
3. Run a bash script.
4. Go to step 1.

I know only how to complete step 3, the first 2 steps are out of my coding skill.
Can you help me?

Comment: I am not sure about osx, but see if it has something equivalent of "`framebuffer`"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the first step, but you could take a screenshot and use ImageMagick to [print the colors of pixels](http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15912).

```
tmp=/tmp/$(uuidgen).png
trap "rm $tmp" exit
screencapture $tmp
/usr/local/bin/convert $tmp[1x1+1000+500] $tmp[1x1+1100+500]\
$tmp[1x1+1000+510] $tmp[1x1+1100+510] txt: | grep '#FFFFFF' || exit
```

Comment: Note: this is somewhat an expensive operation so I wouldn't do it often (more than once per second).

Comment: I'd rather use `rgba:- | od -An -tx1`

Comment: Regarding the performance concern geowar raised: for small PNGs it runs here at 40 files per second on a 2013 laptop with a museum piece of a hard drive, so speed seems alright. However, beware that it's tempting to assume it always outputs srgba values because it usually does... except sometimes it'll find a named color and output something like "chartreuse" in place of the srgba value (I was checking for the redness of a pixel).

Answer (score 1):

As for checking for keystrokes, I use this command line tool:

http://www.klieme.ch/pub/checkModifierKeys.zip

, which is discussed on macscripter.net (sorry, can't post this as link).
This command line command is utilized in a similar fashion to what I describe below ("do shell script").
Another command line tool is used to get the pixel position of the mouse:

www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/

*(again, sorry for inability to post this as link).*

For getting pixel color ...

See my blog post about using python for this (my method is based on similar solutions):
http://thechrisgreen.blogspot.com/2013/04/python-script-for-getting-pixel-color.html

I have an AppleScript script that does "do shell script" with this python script, sets a variable "rgb" to the (string) result, then does

```
run script rgb
```

which gets you a list like

```
{255,255,255}
```

Seeing this rather late in the game ... this is for future surfers I guess ...